# A-Frame (aframe.io) 360 degree image (Google Maps Streetview-like functionality)

Tags: aframe, 360-virtual-reality

I have a 360 degree image that I'm using a-frame to display.

My question is, is there any interactivity (like Google Maps Street View) where I can take overlay arrows and take the user to another 360 degree image? Is it possible to do this? How would I go about adding this type of functionality if it is possible?

Is it possible to add text or html links onto the 360 image?

I realize that's more than one question but hopefully someone can help me out. I 'm really liking A-Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what You want to achieve.

**A 360 gallery ( like google maps street view ):**

The easiest way is to make a sphere/sky which is changing its source image. Examples [here](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/), tutorial [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/guides/building-a-360-image-gallery.html). 
Basically You make either a `<a-sky>` or `<a-sphere>` with the source of your image like `<a-sphere src="myImage.jpg">` or `<a-sphere material="src:myImage.jpg">`. Of course, you would like to have the buttons all over the place, not organized like in the example.

**Links**

Im not sure about adding normal links, of course you may add any entity, which would redirect you to another page via javascript like this:
in the scene:

```
<a-entity link><a-entity>
```

@js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('link', {
        init:function(){
           this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
                 window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
           });
        }
      });
```

**Text**

Adding text is documented [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/text.html). If you don't like it, you can always make an image with an alpha channel and add it wherever You like.

To be honest, try making a 360 image, then make a 2D picture, then work on some behavior ( links, switching images ).

Comment: thanks, i saw the example of the 360 image gallery, but did not realize there was a tutorial.